# How to get nested json data from MetaWeather API to my angular project? (parsing through the nested json data

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I have to get the weather data for a location with my angular project. The problem is that the weather data json given back to me through the api is in the json format like:

```
// 20201008222926
// https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/44418/

{
  "consolidated_weather": [
    {
      "id": 4674059431313408,
      "weather_state_name": "Heavy Rain",
      "weather_state_abbr": "hr",
      "wind_direction_compass": "WSW",
      "created": "2020-10-08T15:20:03.589494Z",
      "applicable_date": "2020-10-08",
      "min_temp": 11.5,
      "max_temp": 16.785,
      "the_temp": 16.66,
      "wind_speed": 9.83045090573186,
      "wind_direction": 248.82844523596123,
      "air_pressure": 1010.0,
      "humidity": 78,
      "visibility": 8.678070070786607,
      "predictability": 77
    },
    {
      "id": 6003142362660864,
      "weather_state_name": "Light Rain",
      "weather_state_abbr": "lr",
      "wind_direction_compass": "W",
      "created": "2020-10-08T15:20:03.607143Z",
      "applicable_date": "2020-10-09",
      "min_temp": 8.815,
      "max_temp": 14.14,
      "the_temp": 14.335,
      "wind_speed": 7.377474264757815,
      "wind_direction": 259.17206614672773,
      "air_pressure": 1018.0,
      "humidity": 63,
      "visibility": 13.095087190805694,
      "predictability": 75
    },
    {
      "id": 4516517682085888,
      "weather_state_name": "Light Cloud",
      "weather_state_abbr": "lc",
      "wind_direction_compass": "WNW",
      "created": "2020-10-08T15:20:02.190507Z",
      "applicable_date": "2020-10-10",
      "min_temp": 7.140000000000001,
      "max_temp": 13.61,
      "the_temp": 13.065000000000001,
      "wind_speed": 7.92296388219465,
      "wind_direction": 301.81684613239247,
      "air_pressure": 1023.0,
      "humidity": 63,
      "visibility": 12.806460272011453,
      "predictability": 70
    },
    {
      "id": 6157688506417152,
      "weather_state_name": "Light Cloud",
      "weather_state_abbr": "lc",
      "wind_direction_compass": "NNW",
      "created": "2020-10-08T15:20:02.712238Z",
      "applicable_date": "2020-10-11",
      "min_temp": 7.285,
      "max_temp": 13.225000000000001,
      "the_temp": 13.285,
      "wind_speed": 7.911844851941993,
      "wind_direction": 337.16727710854525,
      "air_pressure": 1025.0,
      "humidity": 65,
      "visibility": 16.299809114769744,
      "predictability": 70
    },
    {
      "id": 6262019231580160,
      "weather_state_name": "Heavy Rain",
      "weather_state_abbr": "hr",
      "wind_direction_compass": "WSW",
      "created": "2020-10-08T15:20:03.978805Z",
      "applicable_date": "2020-10-12",
      "min_temp": 7.609999999999999,
      "max_temp": 11.03,
      "the_temp": 11.12,
      "wind_speed": 5.489960696611788,
      "wind_direction": 241.24751552592497,
      "air_pressure": 1018.0,
      "humidity": 81,
      "visibility": 9.500765529308836,
      "predictability": 77
    },
    {
      "id": 4686520134926336,
      "weather_state_name": "Heavy Rain",
      "weather_state_abbr": "hr",
      "wind_direction_compass": "NW",
      "created": "2020-10-08T15:20:05.203084Z",
      "applicable_date": "2020-10-13",
      "min_temp": 7.865,
      "max_temp": 12.79,
      "the_temp": 12.49,
      "wind_speed": 4.726087051618547,
      "wind_direction": 317.5,
      "air_pressure": 1016.0,
      "humidity": 76,
      "visibility": 9.999726596675416,
      "predictability": 77
    }
  ],
  "time": "2020-10-08T17:59:26.359175+01:00",
  "sun_rise": "2020-10-08T07:13:19.288596+01:00",
  "sun_set": "2020-10-08T18:21:36.880563+01:00",
  "timezone_name": "LMT",
  "parent": {
    "title": "England",
    "location_type": "Region / State / Province",
    "woeid": 24554868,
    "latt_long": "52.883560,-1.974060"
  },
  "sources": [
    {
      "title": "BBC",
      "slug": "bbc",
      "url": "http://www.bbc.co.uk/weather/",
      "crawl_rate": 360
    },
    {
      "title": "Forecast.io",
      "slug": "forecast-io",
      "url": "http://forecast.io/",
      "crawl_rate": 480
    },
    {
      "title": "HAMweather",
      "slug": "hamweather",
      "url": "http://www.hamweather.com/",
      "crawl_rate": 360
    },
    {
      "title": "Met Office",
      "slug": "met-office",
      "url": "http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/",
      "crawl_rate": 180
    },
    {
      "title": "OpenWeatherMap",
      "slug": "openweathermap",
      "url": "http://openweathermap.org/",
      "crawl_rate": 360
    },
    {
      "title": "Weather Underground",
      "slug": "wunderground",
      "url": "https://www.wunderground.com/?apiref=fc30dc3cd224e19b",
      "crawl_rate": 720
    },
    {
      "title": "World Weather Online",
      "slug": "world-weather-online",
      "url": "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/",
      "crawl_rate": 360
    }
  ],
  "title": "London",
  "location_type": "City",
  "woeid": 44418,
  "latt_long": "51.506321,-0.12714",
  "timezone": "Europe/London"
}
```

I tried a lot in my service function to parse through the observables and access the nested consolidated weather array but to no avail; The rest of my data is below;

```js
getWeather(woeid: number): Observable<any>{
    const url= `${this.weatherUrl}${woeid}/`;
    return this.http.get<Weather.RootObject>(this.weatherUrl);
     
    //.subscribe.map(this.u=> this.u=Weather.RootObject.consolidated_weather);
    //.pipe(
     // catchError(this.errorHandler<Weather.RootObject>('weatherfor5days',[]))
    //);
   // return this.http.get<(this.weatherUrl)  
   // .map((res: Response) => res.json().consolidated_weather) 
  }
  
  //would set rObject to store the return of http get in the component class
```

```html
<h2 >Weather Forecast {{w}}</h2>
<mat-card>
    <div *ngFor= "let cons of rObject$">
        <div *ngFor= "let con of cons">
            <mat-card-header><h2>Forecast for {{con.applicable_date}}</h2></mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-content>Current temperature:{{con.the_temp}}</mat-card-content>
        </div>    
    </div>
</mat-card>
```

my interface for storing the weather response, my root object has only consolidated_weather because I only require the weather data not anything else;

```
export namespace Weather{

    export interface ConsolidatedWeather {
        id: any;
        weather_state_name: string;
        weather_state_abbr: string;
        wind_direction_compass: string;
        created: Date;
        applicable_date: string;
        min_temp: number;
        max_temp: number;
        the_temp: number;
        wind_speed: number;
        wind_direction: number;
        air_pressure: number;
        humidity: number;
        visibility: number;
        predictability: number;
    }

    export interface Parent {
        title: string;
        location_type: string;
        woeid: number;
        latt_long: string;
    }

    export interface Source {
        title: string;
        slug: string;
        url: string;
        crawl_rate: number;
    }

    export interface RootObject {
        consolidated_weather: ConsolidatedWeather[];
        
    }

}
```

I had no problem accessing the location data from the api as it was a normal array of json objects, but here since it is a nested json I'm having some difficulty to access the data stored in response from the api.

Comment: I'm having difficulties understanding your problem. What is the expected output and what do you receive right now?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to angular, but the problem is I'm trying to access the nested data within the interface that i use to store the data from the response given by the api. I'm not quite sure how to do this but I have no problem accessing the list of locations from the api. The expected output what I'm supposed to display to the page is the weather data for the next 6 days of a location to a page. But since it is in a nested json response I don't know how to send the request to the api either.

Comment: Can you provide a working test example (on any sandbox server)? Might be easier for me to find out your problem.